# dbus-send version in python

Tags: python, dbus

I have a working dbus-send invocation:

```
#                                   OBJECT          INTERFACE        .MEMBER  CONTENT
dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez /org/bluez/hci0 org.bluez.Adapter.SetMode string:discoverable
```

Now I am trying to do the same in python, but since pitful documentation and despite me trying all thinkable permutations all I get are errors on the **last** step.

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
hci0 = bus.get_object('org.bluez', '/org/bluez/hci0')
# everything good so far

# v1
hci0_setmode = hci0.get_dbus_method('SetMode', 'org.bluez.Adapter')
hci0_setmode('discoverable')

# v2
iface = dbus.Interface(hci0, 'org.bluez.Adapter')
iface.SetMode('discoverable')

# v3
iface = dbus.Interface(hci0, 'org.bluez.Adapter')
hci0_setmode =iface.get_dbus_method('SetMode', 'org.bluez.Adapter')
hci0_setmode('discoverable')
```

Whatever I do, the error is:

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "SetMode" with signature "s" on interface "org.bluez.Adapter" doesn't exist
```

I have not found a way to tell me what mathod with what signatures exist and besides this error message seemingly contradict with the inital dbus-send invocation, which proofs that "org.bluez.Adapter.SetMode(s)" exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by looking at the api:

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.bluez --type=method_call --print-reply /org/bluez/hci0 org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect
```

and here is the python code:

```
import dbus
bus = dbus.SystemBus()
hci0 = bus.get_object('org.bluez', '/org/bluez/hci0')
props = dbus.Interface(hci0, 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties')
props.Set('org.bluez.Adapter1', 'Discoverable', True)
```

I am still not sure why the initial dbus-send command even works. The only reference to SetMode I can find elsewhere is here: http://svn.openmoko.org/developers/erin_yueh/bt/bt_adapter.py.